# How do I do basic authentication with RestClient?

Tags: ruby, github, rest-client

Does anyone know how to do basic authentication with [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)?

I need to create a private repository on GitHub through their RESTful API.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb) it looks like you can just specify user and password as part of your request object.

Have you tried something like:

```
r = Request.new({:user => "username", :password => "password"})
```

Also if you look down in the Shell section of the [ReadMe](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) it has an example of specifying it as part of  `restshell`.

```
$ restclient https://example.com user pass
>> delete '/private/resource'
```

Comment: Consider including the module in usage to improve this. e.g. `RestClient::Request` and adding more context to make the example you gave fully functional

Answer (score 45):

The easiest way is to embed the details in the URL:

```
RestClient.get "http://username:password@example.com"
```

Comment: I was searching how to perform authentication without having to initialize a RestClient::Request. +1 for the usage of RestClient.get method. BUT doesn't username and password require escape? Looks as if it's not as easy as it seemd.

Comment: What if my username has an '@' character?

Comment: ...but if you've special characters like # in your password you've get excetion: 
InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)

Comment: basic auth should go in the headers unless you absolutely have no other choice

Answer (score 36):

Here is an example of working code where I support optional basicauth but don't require the user and password be embedded in the URL:

```
def get_collection(path)
  response = RestClient::Request.new(
    :method => :get,
    :url => "#{@my_url}/#{path}",
    :user => @my_user,
    :password => @my_pass,
    :headers => { :accept => :json, :content_type => :json }
  ).execute
  results = JSON.parse(response.to_str)
end
```

Do note if `@my_user` and `@mypass` are not instantiated, it works fine without basicauth.

Answer (score 8):

This works and follows [RFC 7617 for Http Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617):

```rb
RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post,
  url: "https://example.com",
  headers: { "Authorization" => "Basic " + Base64::encode64(auth_details) },
  payload: { "foo" => "bar"}
)


def auth_details
  ENV.fetch("HTTP_AUTH_USERNAME") + ":" + ENV.fetch("HTTP_AUTH_PASSWORD")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kelsey Hannan:

```rb
RestClient.get("https://example.com", 
  {
    Authorization: "Basic #{Base64::encode64('guest:guest')}"
  }
)

RestClient.post("https://example.com", 
  {  }.to_json,
  {
    Authorization: "Basic #{Base64::encode64('guest:guest')}"
  }
)
```