# POST in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-services, json, rest

How can I call some webservices in rails 3 using POST params to an external URL? I usually use  something like this to post from the command line

```
curl -X POST -u "v10REVkw:XuCqIhyCw" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"apids": ["c80-d363237c-e513b"], "android": {"alert": "Android  Test!"}}' \
https://url/to/push
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would use [Rest client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client). Here is an example straight from their docs:

```
RestClient.post "http://example.com/resource", { 'x' => 1 }.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

Comment: how do you pass username to it?

Comment: If you are doing http basic auth you should be able to just slap it in the url: https://username:password@somesite.com. Github is helpfully making my fake link into a real one but you get the idea.

Comment: Additionally check out this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692574/basic-auth-with-rest-client

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailled way to achieve what you expect extracted from one of my gems.

Just adapt and trigger with `remote`.

```
def remote
  begin
    Net::HTTP.get_response((uri)).body
  rescue 
    #what you want here
  end
end

def gateway
  'http://api.opencalais.com/enlighten/rest/'
end

def uri
  URI.parse(gateway + '?' + URI.escape(post_params.collect{ |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join('&')))
end

def post_params
  {
    'licenseID' => @api_key,
    'content'   => @context
  }
end
```

EDIT:

Be sure you have this included:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
```

EDIT2:

If you're interacting with RESTful webservice, consider using ActiveResource

Comment: thanks! I just have one question, how do I pass in -u option?

Comment: if you want auth, change the gateway as follows: `http://login:pass@www.example.com/todo.cgi`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html), it is part of Rails package.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough that no-one hasn't so far suggested HTTParty, which is imho  one of the simplest HTTP libs out there :)

http://httparty.rubyforge.org/