# How to convert curl code to ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, rest-client

I'm in trouble to convert the curl code below to ruby using Rest-Client library.

curl code:

```
curl https://my_url -u user_token: -F "data[price]=$ 100,00"
```

Ruby code that I tried without success:

```
request = RestClient.new 'https://my_url', user: user_token, password: pwd

request.post :data => { :price => '$ 100,00' }, :multipart => true, :verify_ssl => true
```

Comment: Could you show some Ruby code? It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When more information is requested in the comments, it is best to edit your question to add the relevant information so that new viewers will not have to search through the comments to find all they need to help you. Also, if you show some attempt at a solution off the bat, more people will be inclined to give a helping hand.

Comment: This is an example which grabs the content of a url: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-pEdhY/0/1?curriculum_id=5122d839c0a131c35f00013d combining this with the docs for OpenURI (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) may yield the results you want.

Comment: @the_bear What is the error you are getting?

Comment: no answer, time out. But the curl works well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692574/how-do-i-do-basic-authentication-with-restclient

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a library like curb or curb-fu. They are pretty cool gems and the documentation makes them pretty easy to use.